# Consideraciones para elegir nombres de tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo un programa donde el usario debe ingresar un texto que más adelante será el nombre de una tabla, quisiera saber cuales son las limitantes a la hora de elegir un nombre para estas, haciendo pruebas me encontré conque no pueden empezar con números, porque a la hora de ejecutar las querys me arroja un error, por ejemplo esta:

```
SELECT * FROM 123TABLE
```

Cabe acotar que estoy trabajando en Python así que no se si sea cuestión del lenguaje. En todo caso, ¿Existe parámetros a tener en cuenta para elegir los nombres de las bases de datos? Ya que me gustaría hacer una validación al texto que ingrese el usuario.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Hola. El documento que te indica @BetaM **Es la clave** extracté de el esta nota `For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined object.` para que la tengas presente. Y la razón que aducen es que **son muchísimas las palabras reservadas** e imposible recordarlas (para humanos normales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace un tiempo busqué documentación sobre esto y no la encontré, aunque hoy he encontrado [este enlace](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). En general son admitidos los caracteres del abecedario y algunos símbolos como guiones y puntos. No se pueden utilizar nombres de palabras reservadas.

Al crear la tabla debes rodear su nombre por comillas dobles, que es el estándar en SQLLite3. De esta manera, estos nombres de tabla son válidos:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc"(columnas);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc.txt"(columnas);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc-ABC.txt"(columnas);
```

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, en Python por regla general no se nombra empezando por números, ya que normalmente te daría error a la hora de ejecutar.

La primera regla es que los nombres sólo pueden contener letras, números y barras bajas (solo barras bajas, cuidado ya que los guiones te crearán un error de sintaxis...).

Segundo, Python es "case sensitive" es decir, que es capaz de distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo que no será lo mismo una variable llamada "nombre" que "Nombre" o "nomBRE" por ejemplo.

Te recomiendo que nombres en torno a algo que te sirva de referencia y sea reconocible, tanto como para ti como para el resto de personas que puedan usar/leer tu código.

Te propongo algunos nombres en base a tu código:

```
    Table_123
    Table123
    table1_23
    table12_3
    table123_
```

Comment: Claro ya tenía conocimiento de esto, pero como estaba dentro del string de la query pensé que no importaría, porque no era el nombre de una variable, pero igual daba error, gracias de todas maneras.